# Is the use of punctuation appropriate here?

Tags: punctuation

> For most people, football might just be a game, but for me, it is a way of life.

Is the above sentence correct in terms of punctuation? Or should I write this in the following manner:

> For most people football might just be a game, but for me it is a way of life.

Comment: I would keep all of the commas except for the *last* one. (Which is different from both of your variations.) Also, you need a space after every comma.

Comment: Neither is incorrect, and the current trend is towards minimalist punctuation, so your second variant would get the star prize. If you want 'pauses for thought', the first version codes for these ... but it suffers from 'comma clutter'. The most significant break in the sentence (and hence pause when reading) comes after 'game', and using something more heavy-duty here (a dash or even an ellipsis) works better.

Comment: A sentence is punctuated to remove possible ambiguity.  Here, even without a single comma, one can understand it. That being so, I think we should use minimum of such punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me add a number to each comma in the sentence.

> For most people,(1) football might just be a game,(2) but for me,(3)
> it is a way of life.

Actually, there are precise rules about using commas. See [A Guide To Proper Comma Use - Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9/?IR=T)

> Contrary to popular belief, commas don't just signify pauses in a
> sentence.
>
> In fact, precise rules govern when to use this punctuation mark. When
> followed, they lay the groundwork for clear written communication.

The 2nd comma is OK. Because "For most people, football might just be a game" and "for me, it is a way of life" are both independent clauses.

> 1. Use a comma before any coordinating conjunction (and, but, for, or, nor, so, yet) that links two independent clauses.
>
> Example: "I went running, and I saw a duck."

Then it comes to the 1st and the 3rd comma. Consider this sentence:

> For most people, football might just be a game.

I believe "For most people" is an adverb clause according to [What are Adverb Clauses? Examples & Exercises](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adverb/adverb-clauses/):

> An adverb clause is a group of words that is used to change or qualify
> the meaning of an adjective, a verb, a clause, another adverb, or any
> other type of word or phrase with the exception of determiners and
> adjectives that directly modify nouns.

According to [this page](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-dependent-clauses.html), an adverb clause is a dependent clause:

> A dependent clause is a group of words with a subject and a verb. It
> does not express a complete thought so it is not a sentence and can't
> stand alone. **These clauses include adverb clauses**, adjective clauses
> and noun clauses.

Now back to my first reference, [A Guide To Proper Comma Use - Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9/?IR=T):

> 2. **Use a comma after a dependent clause that starts a sentence**.
>
> Example: "When I went running, I saw a duck."
>
> A dependent clause is a grammatical unit that contains both subject
> and verb but cannot stand on its own, like "When I went running ..."
>
> **Commas always follow these clauses at the start of a sentence.** If a
> dependent clause ends the sentence, however, it no longer requires a
> comma. Only use a comma to separate a dependent clause at the end of a
> sentence for added emphasis, usually when negation occurs.

So, there should be a comma after "For most people" and "for me".

So, all of the 3 commas are OK.

Comment: “There are precise rules about commas”. Indeed there are. A pity that the rule books all differ.

Answer (score -1):

"For most people football might just be a game, but for me it is a way of life" is just fine, but you could even leave out the remaining comma.

The first and last commas in the first sentence are wrong. The test here is if you have a comma not followed by a conjunction, the offset phrase ought to be detail, and not strictly needed.

That might render "For most people it is a way of life", which is clearly not the intention of the original sentence.

Comment: l think the first comma is fine. Why is it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't clarify anything. It's extraneous.

Comment: With no commas, you are setting up for a different parsing, e.g., "For most people football might just be *a game but for the violence*....